# How to get complement of a pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I have a list. I want to get all the elements in that list which do not match a given pattern. That is, I want the strings which do not match any of the following patterns:

1. First and last characters are the same: $123aw1$
2. Does not have two consecutive similar characters: $1era22we,
       awe33rt, 123aa123$

I wrote following code

```
inputset = ToString /@ {
  11223434, 12123434, 11234342, 11234243, 11234234, 11232434, 12132434, 
  12134234, 11234324, 11232443, 11234423, 12134243, 12314234, 12314324, 
  12341234, 11223344, 11223443, 11234432
};
outputset = Complement[inputset, 
  Select[inputset, 
    StringMatchQ[#, StringExpression[x_, ___, x_]] || 
      StringMatchQ[#, StringExpression[___, x_, x_, ___]] &]];
```

and I got

> ```
> outputset = {12123434, 12132434, 12134234, 12134243, 12314234, 12314324, 12341234}
> ```

Is there an easy simple and efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why not just negate your pattern in `Select` with `!(PATTERN)`?

Comment: Did you take a look at `Except`?

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom `Except` is pretty limited on string patterns, it only works on one character. You can't use it like: `StringMatchQ[{"abc","xyz"}, Except["abc"]]`

Comment: What is the measure of similarity for "two consecutive similar characters"?

Comment: I mean same character appear at position "i" and position "i+1" of given string. "i" can be any position. So I don't want string like "1123", "23345","145aa". Also I don't want string which has same character at beginning and end like "a12wea", "12w33qw1", "2ert442"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select[inputset, Not@(StringMatchQ[#, x_ ~~ __ ~~ x_] || 
                      StringMatchQ[#, ___ ~~ y_ ~~ y_ ~~ ___]) &]
```

[I'm always suspicious about the use of `Alternatives[]` in string patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32515/193), but in this case it seems to work. So you may also write a more compact form:

```
Select[inputset, ! StringMatchQ[#, (x_ ~~ __ ~~ x_)  | ( ___ ~~ y_ ~~ y_ ~~ ___)] &]
```

Note the need for parenthesizing.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pick.html):

```
Pick[
  inputset,
  StringMatchQ[inputset, (x_ ~~ __ ~~ x_) | (___ ~~ y_ ~~ y_ ~~ ___)],
  False];
```