# Named string patterns in Alternatives, why does it depend on order?

Tags: string-manipulation

When using the same name for part of patterns inside `Alternatives` how come it behaves differently for strings than in normal patterns?

```
{StringMatchQ["ab", (x_ ~~ "c") | ("a" ~~ x_)],
 StringMatchQ["ab", ("a" ~~ x_) | (x_ ~~ "c")]}
(* False, True *)

{MatchQ[{1, 2}, {x_, 3} | {1, x_}],
 MatchQ[{1, 2}, {1, x_} | {x_, 3}]}
(* True, True *)

StringMatchQ["ab", (x_ ~~ "c") | (x_ ~~ "b")]
(* False *)
```

Comment: You are binding the first x_ with the first alternative. Try `{StringMatchQ["ab", (x_ ~~ "c") | ("a" ~~ y_)], 
 StringMatchQ["ab", ("a" ~~ x_) | (y_ ~~ "c")]}` instead

Comment: @belisarius I don't think it's that simple, look for instance at: `StringMatchQ["ab", (x_ ~~ "c") | (x_ ~~ "b")]` if x was bound to "a" then it would still match on the second one

Comment: perhaps x is bound to Undefined in the first try. Just ranting. Of course if you replace the secon x_ by y_, it works again

Comment: You may see that x_ becomes bounded to an empty string `FullForm@StringReplace["ab", 
  Alternatives[(x_ ~~ "c"), ("a" ~~ y_)] :> 2 x]`

Comment: String patterns are fundamentally different from ordinary patterns, as they are actually converted into regular expressions and passed off to the PCRE library for processing. As such, their features, limitations, and behaviors are exactly those of PCREs. Why this particular behavior arises I don't personally know, but if you look into the PCRE documentation you might find an answer.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Interesting, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @OleksandrR pointed out string patterns are translated to [PCRE](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

[The tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html),in the *Implementation Details* section, mentions `PatternConvert` that shows the translation used:

```
StringPattern`PatternConvert[(x_ ~~ "c") | ("a" ~~ x_)]
(* {"(?ms)(?:(.)c|a(?:\\1))", {{Hold[x], 1}}, {}, Hold[None]} *)
```

The relevant part here is `(?:(.)c|a(?:\1))` when I was expecting something like: `(?:(?<x>.)c|a(?<x>.))`