# Weird behaviour of HoldPattern

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, documentation

I'm still thinking about how to implement `Condition` with anonymous patterns. And now I think I've found a way to implement it, but again, a suspected unclear documentation blocked me......

It's said in documentation that:

> `HoldPattern[expr]` is equivalent to *expr* for pattern matching, but maintains *expr* in an unevaluated form.

---

But in this example, I simply adds a `HoldPattern` to the original okay pattern, then it generates a message and stop evaluation:

```
{{},{a,a},{a,b},{a,a,a}}/.{(Pattern[Evaluate[x=Unique[]],_]/;(Echo@x; True))..}->xxx
```

> A seires of `$--an integer--` is returned

```
{{},{a,a},{a,b},{a,a,a}}/.{HoldPattern[(Pattern[Evaluate[x=Unique[]],_]/;(Echo@x; True))]..}->xxx
```

> Pattern: First element in pattern `Pattern[Evaluate[x=Unique[]],_]` is not a valid pattern name.

---

It seems that `HoldPattern` didn't really hold the pattern all the time, or else it won't say those Pattern stuff is invalid because when actually evaluating, the `x=Unique[]` will evaluate first then everything will be fine.

Is this yet another unclear explanation in documentation or it's my mis-implementation of `HoldPattern`?

And are there anyway I can solve this problem?

Thanks!

---

## Some further explanation

I found out that though we cannot easily use anonymous pattern with `Condition` directly, we can create some single use symbol using `Unique[]` and then use them as names used in `Condition`. This will be identical as anonymous `Condition`, right~ But one crucial thing is to let `Unique[]` run again and again in multiple matches instead of calculating only once and leave there.

`HoldPattern` is designed for this job as it will surpress calculation in the first place and rerun each time pattern matcher want to check a match. But it seems that `HoldPattern` did something when nothing should be done, probably something like pre-processing, which result in this situation.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to avoid naming the pattern inside `Condition`?

Answer (score 5):

`HoldPattern` has the attribute `HoldAll`.  Because of this `Evaluate[x=Unique[]]` never evaluates to a symbol. Notice that `Evaluate` is not at the first level within `HoldPattern`, thus it will have no effect.

Note the difference:

```
Hold[Evaluate[1+1]]
(* Hold[2] *)

Hold[ f[Evaluate[1+1]] ]
(* Hold[f[Evaluate[1 + 1]]] *)
```

`Evaluate` has an effect *only at the first level* within a function with `Hold*` attribute.

Comment: so are there any solution to this? I mean, "design something similar to HoldPattern but holds only when inputting, in other words, having a HoldFirst attribute."

Comment: @Wjx define "inputting".

Comment: I mean to store the content of `HoldPattern` in its original way using `HoldAll` attribute. keep the whole thing free from pre-processing. then when using it in pattern matching tests, release all the holds and run just like a normal expression. just like what a function with `HoldAll` attribute usually do.

Comment: So, make it simpler, how to let Evaluate run wherever it is?

Comment: @Wjx That is not possible due to how the evaluator works.  The evaluator *simply doesn't look beyond level 1* inside of an expression with the HoldAll attribute.   What you could do, in general (not necessarily here), is to use `Replace`/`ReplaceAll` to replace `Evaluate[...]` with its evaluated version, wherever it is in a held expression.

Comment: @Wjx But the ultimate question is: what are you trying to achieve here?  I don't see any use for the pattern you are constructing. I am not saying that there isn't, but I don't see it, so could you explain?  You seem to imply that you've written about why you want "anonymous conditions" before but I didn't find those posts.

Comment: I'm still trying to solve [this problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123290/dealing-with-repeated-and-pattern-at-the-same-time) and I want to create a solution similar to WReach's second post with a brunch of `Repeated` but I would like to let the `name1` to `name5` generate themselves in pattern matching process.

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, I think I know what's happening here. I think it is that the documentation is a bit ambiguous:

`HoldPattern` actually will hold the whole pattern all the time and only recognize all pattern matching parts like `_`, `__` or `___`. So for example, I use `HoldPattern[Plus[_,_]]` it will hold everything even in pattern matching process. So actually `HoldPattern` is not eqivelent to normal patterns even when matching.

So in my case, `HoldPattern` even hold the naming part in `Pattern[Evaluate[x=Unique[]],_]` and in pattern matching, it will try to find something like `Evaluate[x=Unique[]]_` but without evaluation. of couse only symbol is accepted in the first part of `Pattern`, so though in evaluations, `Evaluate[x=Unique[]]` returns a symbol, in `HoldPattern`, it will just stay in `HoldForm` and keep as an `Expression`, which leads to the error message.

So my question now is how to design something similar to `HoldPattern` but holds only when inputting, in other words, having a `HoldFirst` attribute.

Comment: That's probably subjective but I see your point. Maybe you could reduce your question so that it becomes a more generic/readable for future readers?

Comment: The only way I can think of getting around this problem is to inject the evaluated expression using `With`.

Comment: @QuantumDot great idea! Why not post an answer? I would like to offer an bounty if you really succeeded! :)