# Can we change a pattern once we throw them into pattern matcher?

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, core-language

### Main Problem

Mathematica's pattern matching mechanism seems fairly well in most cases but in some situations, I would like to ask for a bit more freedom.

We can easily call for extra evaluation while testing whether a pattern is valid, even changing the test condition if we want:

```
Block[{i},MatchQ[Range@10, {(_?((If[Head[i] === Symbol, i = #, i = i + 1]; # == i) &)) ..}]]
```

In this case, the test condition will change with an external variable `i`.

So my problem is, **could we do the same to a pattern itself?**

For Example, Enter an expression like `If[TrueQ@x,a_,b_]` to tell pattern matcher: Call for extra evaluation to deternmin what **exactly** this pattern should be **in this place**.

If this could be achieved, a whole branch of evaluation would be possible, the most significant one, in my opinion, could be the generation of anonymous `Condition` by generating unique variable at runtime. This would enable the usage of Combining `Repeated` with `Condition` which cannot be easily achieved now, check [this place](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123290/dealing-with-repeated-and-pattern-at-the-same-time).

---

### A toy code here to illustrate my point clearer:

I would like to check whether a sequence could be written as a series of small sequences with two elements each, As `PatternTest` would test the elements one by one, while I need to test them as a whole to check whether the length of the sequence is 2, I must use `Condition`, so I wrote the following code:

```
MatchQ[#,{(x__/;Length[{x}]==2)..}]&/@{{1,2,1,2},{1,2,3,4}}
```

It returns `{True,False}`, but I would like to make it generate `{True,True}`, as both of them could be interpreted as two repeated sequence with two elements each. but in order to use `Condition`, I must declare the name of the pattern, but once I've declared a stationary name of the pattern, `Repeated` would work in a not desired way.

An easy solution is to change the pattern's name upon each evaluation of this pattern, something like:

```
{(Pattern[x,__]/;(x=Unique[];Length[{x}]==2))..}
```

But it won't work as desired easily because it requires to change the pattern `Pattern[x,__]` according to the name stored in global variable `x` at runtime.

---

### Toy example 2

Reduce the following code:

```
MatchQ[{a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b},{PatternSequence[x_, y_] ..}]
```

To something like

```
Block[{i=0},MatchQ[{a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b},{If[OddQ[++i],x_,y_]..}]]
```

Note that the second differs from the first that it could match something like `[{a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a}`, but let's ignore that, sometimes we even want this effect, e.g. finding recursive loops.

Comment: In something like `Repeated[patt /; cond]` the patt part is evaluated only once, not every time a match is attempted. So I think what you're asking would require a fundamental change to the internals of the pattern matcher.

Comment: @SimonWoods Yes, It only evaluate once in all the cases I know, but maybe there's some undocumented way to force calculation? Just like normally in a replace operation, rep in patt->rep won't be calculated, but one can use in place eval technique to force evaluation. Or simply use the undocumented `RuleCondition`. I'm just wondering whether there're any similar secret operations that can force the evaluation of patt at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I can deal with the sequence matching without names:

```
$s={};
a = Function[AppendTo[$s, #];True];
b[c_] := ($s={};#)&[c@$s]

MatchQ[{(__?a/;b[Length@#===2&])..}] /@ {{1,2,1,2},{1,2,3,4}}
(* {True, True} *)
```

But I think there's no advantage of pattern-matching performance anymore. And the requirement for three definitions takes the beauty away. Maybe this solution is useless.

Maybe this is quite a pitfall of the language design.